# An affine transformation $g$ map lines which intersect at $P$ to lines which intersect at $g(P)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

So the proof is of the statement

> An affine transformation $g$ of $\mathbb{R^2}$ maps straight lines to straight lines.

Say $g(P) = MP + D$ for $P \in \mathbb{R^2}$. Suppose that the equation of a line $l$ is $ax+by = c$, this can be written as $[a \space b][x\space  y]^T  = c$. If the point $[x\space  y]^T$ is on $l$,

$$([a \space b]M^{-1})(M[x \space y]^T + D) = c + [a \space b ]M^{-1}D$$

letting $[a' \space b'] = [a \space b]M^{-1}$ and $c' = c + [a \space b ]M^{-1}D$, we have

$[a' \space b'](M[x \space y]^T + D) = c'$

which shows that if $[x \space y]^T$ lies on $l$ then then $g([x \space y]^T)$ lies on the line $[a' \space b'][x \space y]^T = c'$

This is okay. The reader is asked to show that if we have two parallel  lines that don't intersect then $g$ maps these lines to parallel lines that do not intersect. This part is really simple, we just note that the lines $[a \space b][x \space y]^T = c$,$[a \space b][x \space y]^T = d$ are mapped to

$[a' \space b'][x \space y]^T = c'$ and $[a' \space b'][x \space y]^T = d'$

and show that $c \neq d \implies c' \neq d' $

however,

> I would like to show that $g$ maps intersecting lines, at $P$ say, to lines that intersect at $g(P)$.

Using the framework of the proof so far I am finding this a difficult task. Say we have two lines

$[a \space b][x \space y]^T = c$ ,$[e \space f][x \space y]^T = d$

that intersect at $P$, under $g$ these lines are mapped to the lines

$[a' \space b'][x \space y]^T = c'$ ,$[e' \space f'][x \space y]^T = d'$

I started to consider

$$c' - d' = ([a' \space b'] - [e' \space f'])[x \space y]^T$$
$$=([a \space b] - [e \space f])M^{-1}[x \space y]^T$$

Or

$$c' - d' = c - d + ([a \space b] - [e \space f])M^{-1}D  =([a \space b] - [e \space f])[x \space y]^T + ([a \space b] - [e \space f])M^{-1}D$$

I do not know where to go with this.

Comment: Hint: If $x\in L$ and $f: L\to L'$, then $f(x)\in L'$, where $L, L'$ are any sets, $x$ is any element of $L$ and $f$ is any map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simpler than what you have. Think of the lines $l_1$ and $l_2$ which intersect at the point $P \in \mathbb R^2$ as *subsets* of $\mathbb R^2$ (rather than functions). The affine transformation $g$ is just a function $g : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$. Since $P \in l_1 \cap l_2$, it follows that $g(P) \in g(l_1 \cap l_2)$. Since $g(l_1 \cap l_2) \subseteq g(l_1) \cap g(l_2)$, we have $g(P) \in g(l_1) \cap g(l_2)$, as desired.

You have to prove the inclusion $g(l_1 \cap l_2) \subseteq g(l_1) \cap g(l_2)$ (if you haven't already). It's the following theorem: If $f : X \to Y$ is a function between sets $X$ and $Y$, and $A, B$ are subsets of $X$, then $f(A \cap B) \subseteq f(A) \cap f(B)$.

Comment: Should it be ...$g(P) \in g(l_1) \cap g(l_2)$, as desired?